# Использование Denwer для работы с базой данных в C++

Tags: c++, mysql, denwer

Доброе время суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, мне в понимании процесса связи приложения C++ с Denwer.

Раньше я использовал Denwer для другого своего проекта, не связанного с C++. Подключение к базе данных и работа с базой данных работали и работает хорошо.

Теперь я пытаюсь провернуть ту же операцию со своим приложением, написанным на языке C++. У меня написан весь код, подключены необходимые библиотеки. Но при самом подключении к базе данных в логах появляется ошибка №2003 ("Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)"). Я вот и думаю, может не хватает какого-то приложения, которое бы помогло в связке моего приложения с Denwer?

Answer (score 0):

Для сервера на C# не требуется Denwer. Вы ведь открывали порт на локальном хосте?
Установите отдельно БД и подключитесь к ней. Либо, что ещё лучше - установите OpenServer, в нем есть несколько баз данных и админ-панелей для них, к этому есть ещё и пара клиентов (программ) которые вы можете запустить локально для работы с БД.

Comment: Простите, то есть Denwer и встроенная в него phpMyAdmin мне не помогут? Обязательно нужен OpenServer?

Comment: Нет. Вы можете пользоваться БД с Denwer, либо установить любую БД отдельно, но под виндой удобнее работать с OpenServer.